# Separate a long string of Dates and Times

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have the following string in PHP:

```
$date_range_create_event = "Jan 12, 2019 08:00 PM - Feb 14, 2019 06:00 AM";
```

I would like to separate it into 4 parts and then be able to access them as variables:

- start date (Jan 12, 2019)
- start time (08:00 PM)
- end date (Feb 14, 2019)
- end time (06:00 AM)

I would like to make this dynamic. Is there anything I can do via code to separate this automatically?

Edit:

Here is what I've tried to extract the start date:

```
$start_date = substr($date_range_create_event, 0, strpos($date_range_create_event, ' ', strpos($date_range_create_event, ' ')+1));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, but I can't think of a pattern that matches everything I need unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method tht does not need all the heavy regex is to use explode  in two different ways.

First we explode the different DateTime on " - " then we loop and explode on space.
We know the date has three spaces since there is year, month and day.
Implode three items as the date using array_splice then the rest is the time.

```
$date_range_create_event = "Jan 12, 2019 08:00 PM - Feb 14, 2019 06:00 AM";

$dates = explode(" - ", $date_range_create_event);

foreach($dates as &$date){
    $temp = explode(" ", $date);
    $date = ["date" => implode(" ",array_splice($temp, 0,-2)), "time" => implode(" ", $temp)];
}
unset($date);
```

https://3v4l.org/K4qE7

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from each of the split parts of the string (around the `-`) and then output whatever pieces of the date/time you need, in whatever format you require from the resultant objects:

```
$date_range_create_event = "Jan 12, 2019 08:00 PM - Feb 14, 2019 06:00 AM";
list($start, $end) = array_map(function ($d) { return new DateTime($d); }, explode('-', $date_range_create_event));
echo "Start date = " . $start->format('M j, Y') . "\n";
echo "Start date = " . $start->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
echo "Start time = " . $start->format('h:i A') . "\n";
echo "Start time = " . $start->format('H:i') . "\n";
echo "End date = " . $end->format('M j, Y') . "\n";
echo "End time = " . $end->format('h:i A') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Start date = Jan 12, 2019 
Start date = 2019-01-12 
Start time = 08:00 PM 
Start time = 20:00 
End date = Feb 14, 2019 
End time = 06:00 AM
```

Parsing the input into `DateTime` objects also has advantages such as making it easy to compute the duration of the event:

```
$duration = $start->diff($end);
echo "Event is " . $duration->format('%h') . " hours and " . $duration->format('%i') . " minutes long\n";
```

Output:

```
Event is 10 hours and 0 minutes long
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HMigso)

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_map('date_parse', preg_split('~\s*-\s*~', $date_range_create_event));`

This gives an array like the one below. The rest shout be very simple.

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(12) {
    'year' =>
    int(2019)
    'month' =>
    int(1)
    'day' =>
    int(12)
    'hour' =>
    int(20)
    'minute' =>
    int(0)
    'second' =>
    int(0)
    'fraction' =>
    double(0)
    'warning_count' =>
    int(0)
    'warnings' =>
    array(0) {
    }
    'error_count' =>
    int(0)
    'errors' =>
    array(0) {
    }
    'is_localtime' =>
    bool(false)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(12) {
    'year' =>
    int(2019)
    'month' =>
    int(2)
    'day' =>
    int(14)
    'hour' =>
    int(6)
    'minute' =>
    int(0)
    'second' =>
    int(0)
    'fraction' =>
    double(0)
    'warning_count' =>
    int(0)
    'warnings' =>
    array(0) {
    }
    'error_count' =>
    int(0)
    'errors' =>
    array(0) {
    }
    'is_localtime' =>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Preg_split in an array_map means you are looping regex. That is not a good idea on a "long string" as OP describes it.

Comment: No, @Andreas the `preg_` call is not being iterated, it is being performed just once.  The output of the split is what is being iterated and those values are being parsed into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a combination of regex split and match:

```
$input = "Jan 12, 2019 08:00 PM - Feb 14, 2019 06:00 AM"; 
$parts = preg_split ("/\s+-\s+/", $input);
foreach($parts as $date) {
    if (preg_match("/([a-z]{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM))/i", $date, $results)) {
        echo "date: " . $results[1] . "\n";
        echo "time: " . $results[2] . "\n";
    }
}

date: Jan 12, 2019
time: 08:00 PM
date: Feb 14, 2019
time: 06:00 AM
```

Comment: OP doesn't understand regex, blindly copy-pasted your snippet, and this snippet lead to a follow up question when day was single integer.  Perhaps you could explain. the regex.  Why use `preg_split()` at all -- seems overkill to me because there is no variability.

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to split the string into the four parts, then you can do this in one `preg_` call to explode on the two delimiters.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbecc34e67bc44587cb1851d4253ff0c5a59bda1))

```
$date_range_create_event = "Feb 13, 2019 03:00 PM - Mar 1, 2019 11:00 PM";

$parts = preg_split ("/ - | (?=\d\d:)/", $date_range_create_event);
var_export($parts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Feb 13, 2019',
  1 => '03:00 PM',
  2 => 'Mar 1, 2019',
  3 => '11:00 PM',
)
```

From this, you can use `list()` or php7+ "array deconstruction" to assign the values to variables.

The pattern says, split every time you encounter:

1. a space, hyphen, space or
2. a space (which is trailed by 2 hour digits, then a colon)  The `(?=...)` lookahead is used so that the time substring is not "consumed" as part of the delimiting substring in the process.